# How to do use nested condition in AndWhere in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

Before marking as duplicate question,kindly read it. I have different problem here. I want to generate this kind of Query using yii2 search model.

```
select * from t1 innerjoin t2 on (t1.id = t2.id) where ((t1.price >= '1000' and t1.price <= '5000') OR 
                   ( t2.price >= '1000' and t2.price <= '5000' ))
```

Joining is not a problem here. The main problem is the where clause. I tried this but not working.

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
                     'and',
                     ['>=', 't1.price', $this>start_price],
                     ['<=', 't1.price', $this->end_price]
                 ])
      ->orFilterWhere([
                      'and',
                       ['>=', 't2.price', $this->start_price],
                       ['<=', 't2.price', $this->end_price]
              ]);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'or',
    [
        'and',
        ['>=', 't1.price', $this>start_price],
        ['<=', 't1.price', $this->end_price]
    ],
    [
        'and',
        ['>=', 't2.price', $this->start_price],
        ['<=', 't2.price', $this->end_price]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.. :-)

Comment: Great, Worked For Me Tooo :)

Comment: Thank you, your answer has also helped me.